# Relation between compactness and closure?

Tags: real-analysis

How are compactness and closure related? Suppose $K \subset M$. Suppose the intersection of a collection of open covers $\{G_a\}$ in $M$ yields a finite subcover of $K$. Then this is the closure in some sense of the cover.
I'm attempting to find out how closure and compactness are related; is my argument heading in the right direction?

Comment: Compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed.  In finite dimensional vector spaces, a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.  There are a lot of relationships between them.  Are these the types of things that you are looking for?

Comment: You really haven’t made any argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious way in which closure and compactness are related is this: a closed subset of a compact set is compact.

I'm not quite sure what you mean about the closure of a cover though.  You fix some subset of a set $M$, and then take a collection of open covers, the intersection of which 'yields' a finite subcover of $K$.  In what sense can an intersection of covers yield a finite subcover?

> This is the closure in some sense of the cover.

What cover are you talking about now?  You just had a collection of open covers.  And what is 'this'?

If you clarify your question, and maybe give an example or two, I'll be happy to give you an answer.